# Find lowest z-index of all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently finding the highest z-index of all elements.

```
  var index_highest = 0;

  $(".elem").each(function() {
      var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
      if (index_current > index_highest) {
          index_highest = index_current;
      }

      alert(index_highest);
  });
```

How do I reverse that, to find the lowest z-index of all elements?

Comment: Turn that `>` into a `<`. Then `index_highest` should contain what you are looking for.

Comment: Make sure, you set index_highest = zindex_of_first_element before you run the .each(). Otherwise , you may get wrong values

Comment: Just so you know, if an item doesnt have a zindex defined, it will screw up your idea.  Make sure that all of your elements have a zindex... because it will not natively assign it one based on how it is layered.

Comment: @Fallenreaper - in that case jQuery returns an empty string, wich would parse to NaN

Comment: yes, thats what i am meaning.  if it is NAN, it wouldnt work, but it might have the lowest zindex based on where it is located on the document.  When i think of zindex and such, i always use the 3d webpage viewer for Firefox and Chrome (?) to get an idea.

Comment: @ElliotM: No it won't, that will only work for current_index < 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, take a try:

```
var index_highest = 0,
    index_lowest;

$(".elem").each(function () {
    index_highest = Math.max(parseInt($(this).css("zIndex")), index_highest);
});

index_lowest = index_highest;
$(".elem").each(function(){
    index_lowest = Math.min(parseInt($(this).css("zIndex")), index_lowest);
});

alert(index_highest);
alert(index_lowest);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
var z = $.map($(".elem"), function(el) { 
    return parseInt( el.style.zIndex , 10);
});

var index_lowest  = Math.min.apply( Math, z );
var index_highest = Math.max.apply( Math, z );
```

Comment: Are you sure it is correct ? its giving a NAN -> http://loadmycode.com/build/ekRy8lpoD/2

Comment: @adirohan - Used the OP's code, `$(this).css("zIndex")` returns `auto` for all elements, so it ends up as NaN, edited it

Comment: Looks like it works. This seems less verbose than the answer I ticked. Is it bad etiquette to move a tick after it's awarded?

Comment: @Moppy - That's up to you, generally I'd say it's worse to accept the last answer posted when the others are working and are just as good, but it's your choice

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  var index_lowest = parseInt($(".elem").first().css("zIndex"), 10);    
  $(".elem").each(function() {
      var index_current = parseInt($(this).css("zIndex"), 10);
      if (index_current < index_lowest) {
          index_lowest = index_current;
      }
  });    
  alert(index_lowest);
```